# What's the minimum requirement to run xdebug developement?

Tags: php, mysql, xdebug

I've a very inexpensive virtual server but I get regular stuck in my developement with xdebug and Typo3 websites. Currently I'm running sshd, ftp, xdebug, mysql, postfix on my server and it's only for little developement because mostly I develop on my local box. Is xdebug requirement is heavy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overhead inevitable, though that is getting better. It still exists though, even if it's marked as disabled.

> There is still a bit, about 10%. Xdebug 2.2 (currently SVN-only) have
>   some improvements for this with xdebug.coverage_enable=0  --- https://twitter.com/#!/xdebug/status/50262398933798912

Personally, I'd leave Xdebug off a production server, and try to only run it locally. For profiling, running it live can still be useful, but [XHProfLive](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=62667953919) has been engineered with less no-op overhead, and so I've had that running 1 time in 10,000 live calls before. Most people shouldn't need it anyway (except on a development machine).